# How to sum many INDEX/MATCH values given criteria?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, indexing, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm working on a dataset (30,000 rows x 1,000 columns) that looks like:

```
    Alpha  Beta  Gamma
A     3      4     3
B     4      5     7
C     9      2     4
D     6      9     3
```

I need to add multiple selected values in this format:

```
Selected Values      Total Gamma     Total Alpha    ...etc.
B  C  D  A               17               22        ...etc.
C  A                      7               12        ...etc.
A  D  C                  10               18        ...etc.
```

I could add INDEX/MATCH results one by one and drag down:

```
= IFERROR((INDEX($A$1:$D$6, MATCH($A10, $A$1:$A$6, 0), MATCH(F$9, $A$1:$D$1, 0))), 0) 
+ IFERROR((INDEX($A$1:$D$6, MATCH($B10, $A$1:$A$6, 0), MATCH(F$9, $A$1:$D$1, 0))), 0)
+ so on for each selected value...
```

But as some rows have 500+ selected values (A, B, C ... ZZ), is there a simpler way to add all this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It will likely take some time to calculate all the results because of the multiple criteria and size of the data, but I'd suggest `SUMPRODUCT`, the formula I'm using in H2 is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$D$5*($B$1:$D$1=H$1)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,$G2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Just realised that I had an assumption there: that there are no composite values in the list of 'selected values' (e.g. `Grape` and `Grapefruit`). If there are, then I'd advise ensuring there's something like double spaces between each selected value and at the start and end of the list, then include those spaces in the `SEARCH` function.

Comment: @jackdorian Consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :)